# Ionic 3 how to change the background colour of selected radio button in ion-item container

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I need to change the background color of the selected radio input.

I have the following ion-radio list:

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedRadio">
    <ion-item  *ngFor="let ing of pizzaIng; let i = index">
        <ion-label>{{ing.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio  [value]="ing.name"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The only way it's working, is by overriding `item-md` class of `ion-item` into:

```
ion-item.item-md{
    background-color: red;
}
```

But its changing all the radio options displayed. How can I only change the color of the selected one?

Here is a prepared [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-checkbox-radio-gnwcag) for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got this to work on my ionic 3 project and works in your demo. also just a heads up on using classes with 'md' at the end will only effect android.

.css

```
page-home {
  .item-radio-checked{
      background-color: #a0a;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I change the text inside of the checked radio to white ?